# WSUS stuck at 98%

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

so I was trying to deploy a test update from my WSUS (upstream server) to one of my pc's (both are VMs) and as per checking, it was stuck (Installed 98%) for almost a day now. Now, I've checked everything, the deployed GPO was on the correct OU in which the client pc resides. Configure Auto updates, client side targeting (Group name: WSUS CLIENTS) and Specify intranet MS Update Srvc Location are all enabled (defined intranet: http://mcsa-wds:8530).. If there are things that needs to be cleared or any images that the community will be needing, let me know and I'll provide. Thanking everyone in advance that will spare their time in helping :)

- I've restarted the WDS server and the client pc
- GPUpdate /force was run several times on the client pc

ps: don't get confused, my WSUS service resides on the WDS server.

[image: This is the Update Services]

Comment: Is this about WDS or WSUS, because those are two different things.

Comment: Ohh my sorry got confused, let me edit. this is WSUS.

Comment: To clarify, the update installation on the client is stuck at 98% or it's been installed on 98% of the machines that it's approved for as shown in the WSUS console? Can you post in image of where you're seeing this 98%?

Comment: Hi Joe, I've edited the post and added the picture :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 98% you are looking at refers to the total number of updates installed vs. the total number of applicable updates for that machine.  It does not represent how much of a single update has been installed.  The yellow triangle next to the system name tells me that additional updates need to be approved for the machine.

To get a better idea of what is needed by that machine, add the "Installed", "Failed", and "Needed" columns to your display by right clicking on any of the columns (e.g. Name, IP Address, Operating System).

You can also double-click the machine name to run a report that will tell you what is still needed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the kind feedback :) Saw the updates under "Needed" Status and when I check the updates on the "WSUS Updates" I made, they are showing under  "Approval:Approved" the updates "Approval" is for All computers and on the group name (WSUS Clients) the approval is Install (inherited)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if the update has been installed everywhere, you can do that from the Update section above the computer sections.  You can filter by updates that are needed or unapproved, etc.  If you know what the update is you're looking for, you can run a search for it, however WSUS searching is not always the most friendly thing in the world.